# Android custom attributes on "normal" views?

Tags: android, xml, namespaces, themes

After taking a look at theming for Fede's UberMusic I came across the file album_screen.xml. Below is the source of that file. Basically I noticed that his themes have the ability to use custom views that are a part of his application, and that they have this XML namespace at the top `theme`. I am missing the connection as to how he is able to apply his attributes to views that he does not control, and how Eclipse will compile the cod below without fail. I placed the URL `http://schemas.uberdroidstudio.com/theme` into my browser's address bar but nothing came up, and I cannot figure out where/ how Eclipse knows the attributes that the namespace supports. Thank you ahead of time for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:theme="http://schemas.uberdroidstudio.com/theme">
    <TextView  
        android:id="@id/artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"
        theme:textFilter="uppercase" /> <!-- This is the interesting line -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually not as complicated as I originally thought. XML namespaces are arbitrary strings that just need to be unique. If your namespace does not start with `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res` then it is not validated and the APK package is not checked for `declare-styleable` or the like.
Now a custom namespace if very simple to implement, as illustrated by this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/1105281) in GitHub. Finally, applying custom XML attributes to "normal" widgets can be accomplished by using the [`LayoutInflater.Factory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html) and calling `setFactory` before you inflate your views. Throw it all together and you have a highly theme-able, XML driven application like Fede's UberMusic.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `theme:textFilter="uppercase"` line isn't actually having an effect on the (apparently vanilla) TextView.

As for the URL of the namespace, it is interesting that you can't access it, since it does not appear to be a local styleable (Android would have you refer to a local styleable namespace as `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package`). +1 for novelty.

Comment: If textFilter does not alter the appearance of the TextView then why would he include it? In my tests if I remove it the TextViews are no longer uppercase, and as you mentioned there is no styleable so there is something else at work here. Perhaps it is a custom LayoutInflater?

Comment: @Tom Since you have verified that it has an effect, you have proven my answer wrong. I withdraw it.

Comment: Not necessarily, as I said if he uses a custom LayoutInflater he is not altering the behaviour of a TextView, but simply calling the necessary methods as it appears while the XML is parsed. But that is only a theory, I should hope that there is a better alternative.